# Mount / Link non-existent volume directory to a directory

Tags: mount, directory, redirect

Recently I've removed a volume, `/volume2` and moved all the folders to `/volume1` but many programs are still looking for files under `/volume2`

I want to redirect all `/volume2` requests to `/volume1`

I've tried `mount --bind /volume1/folderX /volume2/folderX` and `ln -s` but it errors out, unable to make the link because `/volume2` doesn't exist.

What can be done to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you have the Volume2 as the first parameter in the `ln -s` command, it works perfectly here when it is the second used.

```
root@zeus-H370M:~# mkdir -p test/Volume1
root@zeus-H370M:~# cd test
root@zeus-H370M:~/test# ln -s Volume1 Volume2
root@zeus-H370M:~/test# ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 11 23:04 Volume1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7 Feb 11 23:05 Volume2 -> Volume1
```